# Trying to detect a windows user switch and close a serial port

Tags: serial-port, switch-user

I have a application I wrote that uses a serial port (hand scanner connected to it) and I need to detect somehow that another user switched so I can close that port and when the new user logs on to the application it wont get 'port in use' error.  Any suggestions?  My program is in VB.Net but open to any suggestions.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue unfortunately.

I find the best thing to do is create a Windows Service to handle all of the comms so that it works independently of any user being logged in. You can use a WCF/Web Service to get data out of the Windows Service.

I hope this helps.

*(I would have posted this as a comment instead of an answer if I could)*